# How to retrieve jenkins build pipeline number?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

In Jenkins I would like to build my test environment based on the "Build Pipeline Number" to make tests and deployment repeatable (on the same source version), but I didn't find any environment variable to retrieve this number. I tried to use the BUILD_ID but it is different for each job (downstream project).

Is it possible to retrieve the Build Pipeline Number? Or is there any other control number that I can use that is the same for all the jobs (increases on a new build)?

Comment: Can you confirm the syntax you used to access the BUILD_ID variable? I've tried ${BUILD_ID} and ${env.BUILD_ID} but neither seem to work. Did you need to load the env at the start of your pipeline definition?

Comment: I could get the build number with env.BUILD_NUMBER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the less popular Delivery pipeline plugin there is a  `PIPELINE_VERSION` environment variable. Otherwise, with the Build pipeline plugin you would probably have to use your VCS revision number and pass it downstream with [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

If you would like to see the list of all current available environment variables just run a batch command `SET` from your build step (or if linux in shell `env`)

Comment: Thanks! I will use the GIT_COMMIT environment variable. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables